# Is there a word/phrase for the reciprocal of frame rate?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

*Frame rate* is to *frequency* as ____ is to *period*?

If a video has a frame rate of 25 fps, the video has a 40ms ____?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frame duration*?

This [quick Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=frame+duration) gives quite a few people who are using it in support questions for video editing, and [here](https://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/fs-1037/dir-016/_2317.htm) is a definition on the website for the Institute for Telecommunication Services:

> **frame duration:** The time between the beginning of a frame and the end of that frame. Note: For fixed-length frames, at a fixed data rate, frame duration is constant.

Comment: "Frame duration" is an example of a **compound noun**.  Compound nouns are permitted in English but they can make your writing seem cold and technical, and even confusing.  I was going to suggest "duration of each frame":   "... the **duration of each frame** *{in the video}* is 40 ms."

Comment: Thanks, I actually end up using **_interval_** in my situation. But I think because of the way I describe the question, especially the example, **_frame duration_** may be more accurate here and I'm going to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @whiskeychief But **frame rate** is a compound noun too, no?

Answer (score 1):

The normal use (at least in my experience, I have a technical/scientific background) is to say the ***interval*** as the elapsed time between events that happen with a known frequency. So if interval is the reciprocal of rate then we might think that frame interval is the reciprocal of frame rate.

However in regards to video, this does not appear to be in common usage.  Typical video encoding techniques do not encode complete frames of video, only partial frames are encoded (to reduce the size of the video data).  The distance betyween the *full* frames is normally known as an interval - either the ***Key Frame interval*** of the ***I Frame interval*** depending on the encoding sceheme, software tools and audience.

[Key frames Explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame)

[Mention of "Frame Interval Timing"](https://support.criticallink.com/redmine/projects/mityccd/wiki/Frame_Interval_Timing_Explained) which is relevant to a particular manufacturer of cameras.

Great Question!